# Matlab: Fsolve giving incorrect roots

Tags: matlab, debugging

I'm trying to solve this system:

```
x = a + e(c - e*x/((x^2+y^2)^(3/2)))
y = b + c(d - e*y/((x^2+y^2)^(3/2)))
```

I'm using `fsolve`, but not matter what I put in as the starting points for the iteration, I get the answer that the starting points are the roots of the equation.

```
close all, clear all, clc

a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
d = 4;
e = 5;

fsolve(@u1FsolveFUNC, [1,2])
```

Function:

```
function outvar = u1FsolveFUNC(invar)

    global a b c d e

    outvar = [...
        -invar(1) + a + e*(c - e*(invar(1) / ((invar(1)^2 + invar(2)^2)^(3/2)))) ; 
        -invar(2) + b + e*(d - e*(invar(2) / ((invar(1)^2 + invar(2)^2)^(3/2))))]

end
```

I could try with `[1,2]` as invariables, and it will say that that is a root to the equation, alltough the correct answer for `[1,2]` is `[12.76,15.52]`

Ideas?

Comment: do you use `global  a b c d e` in your main script too?

Comment: You are aware that your implemented and intended equation differ? The leading `e` in the implementation is a `c` in your description...

Answer (score 2):

If you write your script like this

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
d = 4;
e = 5;

f = @(XY) [...
        -XY(1) + a + e*(c - e*(XY(1) ./ (XY(1).^2 + XY(2).^2).^(3/2))) 
        -XY(2) + b + e*(d - e*(XY(2) ./ (XY(1).^2 + XY(2).^2).^(3/2)))];

fsolve(f, [1,2])
```

it is a lot clearer and cleaner. Moreover, it works :)

It works because you haven't declared `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` and `e` to be `global` before you assigned values to them. You then try to import them in your function, but at that time, they are still not defined as being `global`, so MATLAB thinks you just initialized a bunch of `global`s, setting their initial values to empty (`[]`).

And the solution to an empty equation is the initial value (I immediately admit, this is a bit counter-intuitive).

So this equation involves some inverse-square law...Gravity? Electrodynamics?

Note that, depending on the values of `a-e`, there may be multiple solutions; see this figure:

[image]

Solutions are those points `[X,Y]` where `Z` is simultaneously zero for both equations. for the values you give, there is a point like that at

```
[X,Y] = [15.958213798693690  13.978039302961506]
```

but also at

```
[X,Y] = [0.553696225634946   0.789264790080377]
```

(there's possibly even more...)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using [`global`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) command you have to use the command with all the variables in each function (and main workspace).

eg.

**Main script**

```
global a b c d e % Note
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4; e = 5;   
fsolve(@u1FsolveFUNC,[1,2])
```

**Function**

```
function outvar = u1FsolveFUNC(invar)
global a b c d e % Note
outvar = [-invar(1) + a + e*(c - e*(invar(1) / ((invar(1)^2 + invar(2)^2)^(3/2)))) ; -invar(2) + b + e*(d - e*(invar(2) / ((invar(1)^2 + invar(2)^2)^(3/2))))]
```